# How to chain Observables dynamically by an iterable / list?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I am currently using RxJava and I have something like this,

```
List<Integer> taskIds = ...

Observable.just(new Task(taskIds.get(0)))
        .compose(executeWorkFlow())
        .filter(Response::isSuccess)
        .flatMap(res -> Observable.just(new Task(taskIds.get(1)))
        .compose(executeWorkFlow())
        .filter(Response::isSuccess)
        .flatMap(res -> Observable.just(new Task(taskIds.get(2)))
        .compose(executeWorkFlow())
        .filter(Response::isSuccess)
        ...
```

execute() is a Transformer which performs an API call and returns the response i.e.

```
ObservableTransformer<Task, Response> execute() { ... }
```

Is there a better way of writing this? Given I will not know how many task ids will be emitted from previous Observable.

Comment: Consider using `fromIterable`, `concatMap` and `takeUntil(Predicate)`.

Comment: I have considered `concatMap` but it only allows mapping a sequence of observables without chaining (I need following tasks to only take place if condition is met on the prior task)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fromIterable`, `concatMap` and `takeUntil(Predicate)`:

```
Observable.fromIterable(tasks)
    .concatMap(task ->
        Observable.just(new Task(task))
            .compose(executeWorkFlow())
    )
    .takeUntil(response -> !response.isSuccess)
```

Comment: Hey I have a follow up question. If I want to retrieve the response which is used to create the next Observable<Task>, how would I do that? (Let's say now task is created as such `new Task(task, previousResponse)`)

Comment: Save the previous response in a field or AtomicReference and read it out in concatMap.